# How to get the Default ComboBox from the Visual Studio designer?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've been playing with customizing a combobox in Visual Studio 2019 preview.

I place a combobox in the xaml with:

```
<Combobox x:Name="ComboBoxAddNew" Width="200"/>
```

Then in the Designer, Right-Click on Combobox, Edit Template, Edit Copy. 
Choosing "This:Document"  UserControl:root.

I'm not seeing the PART_EditableTextBox in the generated code.

Help Please.

Comment: This is not possible. Are you absolutely sure or did you just overlooked it? Use text search to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WPF styles and templates can be found in `(VisualStudioInstallDir)\DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf`. For example you can open `aero2.normalcolor.xaml` and search for `ComboBox`.